# Nextcloud slow Frontend, Up- and Download speeds

Tags: php, apache2, nextcloud

I switched from owncloud to nextcloud on my own server a few days ago. I have since but only problems with the cloud and get currently just no further.

Server Down-/Upload: ↓ 111.9 Mbit/s ↑ 37.0 Mbit/s
Client Down-/Upload: ↓ 113.3 Mbit/s ↑ 56.7 Mbit/s

Regarding the slow frontend, I have already gone through all apps and disabled all unnecessary ones. Unfortunately no success with the speed when loading the frontend.

With owncloud I had no speed problems, speeds of 35 Mbit/s upload were achieved without problems. Since the switch to nextcloud, the upload is just 9.5 Mbit/s.

 → this was a driver problem that had crept in stupidly at the same time, I was thinking it could be a DB problem with some sort of long querys issue.

My server is running:

- Ubuntu: 20.04.3 LTS
- Nextcloud: 22.2.0
- PHP: 8.0.11
- MariaDB: 10.3.31
- Apache2: 2.4.41

My Nextcloud config -> config/config.php

```
<?php
$CONFIG = array (
  'instanceid' => '***',
  'passwordsalt' => '***',
  'secret' => '***',
  'trusted_domains' =>
  array (
    0 => 'localhost',
    1 => '***',
    2 => '***',
    3 => '***',
  ),
  'datadirectory' => '***/owncloud/data',
  'dbtype' => 'mysql',
  'version' => '22.2.0.2',
  'overwrite.cli.url' => '***',
  'dbname' => 'nextcloud',
  'dbhost' => 'localhost',
  'dbport' => '',
  'dbtableprefix' => '***',
  'mysql.utf8mb4' => true,
  'dbuser' => '***',
  'dbpassword' => '***',
  'installed' => true,
  'htaccess.RewriteBase' => '/',
  'maintenance' => false,
  'mail_from_address' => 'noreply',
  'mail_smtpmode' => 'smtp',
  'mail_sendmailmode' => 'smtp',
  'mail_domain' => '***',
  'mail_smtpsecure' => 'ssl',
  'mail_smtpauth' => 1,
  'mail_smtpauthtype' => 'LOGIN',
  'mail_smtphost' => '***',
  'mail_smtpport' => '465',
  'mail_smtpname' => '***',
  'mail_smtppassword' => '***',
  'default_phone_region' => 'DE',
  'memcache.local' => '\OC\Memcache\APCu',
  'log_type' => 'file',
  'logtimezone' => 'Europe/Berlin',
  'logfile' => '***/owncloud/data/nextcloud.log',
  'loglevel' => 2,
);
```

I changed following in my php.ini -> etc/php/8.0/apache2/php.ini

```
memory_limit = 512M
apc.enable_cl i =1
```

Please tell me which configuration I still need to post to effectively address the problem.

to increase the probability, the question is asked exactly the same way again in the [forum of nextcloud](https://help.nextcloud.com/t/slow-frontend-up-and-download-speeds/124626).